# Transferring domain to Amazon Route 53. Being asked for NS server's IP addresses

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-route53

I'm trying to migrate an existing domain to Amazon Route 53.  I've followed the guide at:

> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/MigratingDNS.html

My current DNS host is web24.com.au.  There seem to be two areas where the NS records are stored.  I looked in the zone file and updated the NS entries to point to Amazon Route53.  Changing those seems to have made no difference (checked via whois).

I've noticed another section in the configuration portal specifically for nameserver, but in order to change them from the default, I'm being asked to enter both the FQDN of the new name servers and also its IP address.

Amazon have not said anything about the IP address of their name servers (the "Delegation Set"), and I suppose it's simple enough to ping them and get their IPs that way.  But I'm wondering if those name servers are clusters and it's not intended that I supply a single IP address for them.

Is it safe for me to just ping each of the servers in the Route 53 delegation set and use the IP addresses I see when I ping it when transferring the domain from Web24.com.au to Route 53?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer elsewhere on [Amazon's documentation site](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingNewDNS.html#UpdateRegistrarNewDomain):

> Some registrars only allow you to specify name servers using IP addresses; they don't allow you to specify fully qualified domain names. If your registrar requires using IP addresses, you can get the IP addresses for your name servers using the dig utility (for Mac, Unix, or Linux) or the nslookup utility (for Windows).

...and using the dig utility, only a single IP address is returned in the answer section, so using that is okay according to docs.aws.amazon.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the domain registrar settings for your DNS servers.  The zone file you updated also needs to be done, but queries won't use Amazons servers until your registrar is updated.  This updates the DNS root with a new place to resolve your domains; if that data was stored only in your zone file nobody would ever know where to get your zone data from in the first place.

Once you've changed your DNS values on the registrar it might take a day for everything to update.

Comment: That's how I'd normally do it, but the guide over at AWS suggests otherwise.  have you read the AWS guide?